# Is there any arduino microphone that can record heart sound?

Tags: arduino-uno, sound

I'm currently undergoing a project where I record heart sound (mechanical response) and send it over bluetooth to an app.

However I'm finding it really hard to find an arduino microphone or just general microphone that can listen to heart sound.

Any guide would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need three things: a microphone, and amplifier, and an A2DP sender. No need for anything Arduino there.

Comment: How is it possible to connect your microphone to A2DP sender? @Majenko

Comment: With an amplifier and wires.

Comment: it would be better to use an adruino heart beat module, about $2 on ebay...

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no such thing as an Arduino microphone. There are boards specifically for Arduino which have a microphone, but also these are just generic 'electronic sound sensors'.

In principle any microphone would be a valid choice, but you have to test what are the requirements (distance to heart, environment noice). You also could use piezo sensors for vibration checking possibly.

Comment: Apologies for pointing such non existing device. What I'm looking for is a simple micrphone that can just detect heart sound and send over bluetooth. The environment: lets assume a classroom. And generally speaking the microphone should be attached close to your heart (as in your chest).

Comment: https://www.gearbest.com/development-boards/pp_75530.html?currency=GBP&vip=760250&gclid=CjwKCAjwhOvPBRBxEiwAx2nhLlhykouF1qt4QXcvS-roOTPu6pJfeAN4x3KBNUvmFtm34ohKPtwyEhoCQzQQAvD_BwE

Comment: Have a look at this link. Would you think this would be suitable?

Comment: I don't know if it is suitable ... I would say for 2 dollars, buy it and check. If not buy a better one. It could work, since the heart will be close. Btw, for bluetooth sending you need another device, completely unrelated to microphones. Do one step at a time. Hopefully you don't mean 'in your body' ... in that case many more requirements should be met.

Comment: Also for detecting heartbeats there might be a simpler device possible: same as what sport watches use: a 'special ?'  led on a wrist watch on the inside checking the wrist blood-vain.

Comment: As part of this research, I'm opting out from any consumer complete products. ANd yes your right I should take one step at a time. Currently Im so baffled by how we can send microphone data over bluetooth.

Comment: Sending microphone data over bluetooth or any other data does not make much difference. Unless you want to send a lot (like the 'waveform raw data'  of the microphone. But I don't have experience with bluetooth

Comment: Just a thought, depending on your requirements, you might want to consider the use of a small microphone inserted in the tube of a modified stethoscope, or some such.  Prior to their invention, doctors would use a short tube, with one end over the heart, and the other at the ear, thus making the sound readily audible.  I think that detecting the heart beat is the easy part.  Your problem will be sending data by bluetooth, how to then receive and then analyse to produce useful information.